# spawn EACCES error when serving ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic CLI version 4.2.1 and Ionic Framework version 3.9.2. When I try and use `ionic server` in my app I get this error:

> Error: spawn EACCES
>
> at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
>       at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
>       at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:502:9)
>       at spawn
>       (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross- 
>       spawn/index.js:17:18)
>       at spawn
>       (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli- 
>       framework/utils/shell.js:131:12)
>       at ShellCommand.spawn
>       (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli- 
>       framework/utils/shell.js:120:16)
>       at Shell. 
>       (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/shell.js:161:27)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at fulfilled
>       (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
>       at

I got the codebase from another person using the same versions as me, but I have not been able to run it once on my machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is either a permission issue or a a node_modules issue. It's because you transfered the full project folder from another computer.

To resolve the issue, run :

```
npm rebuild
```

To clear npm cache and rebuild your modules

And :

```
chmod 755 -R /yourpath/to/node_modules
```

The error may be caused by an installation of a module which was made in`sudo` mode

Comment: I simply needed to run `npm rebuild`