# ionic serve: ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100 Error: spawn ng EACCES

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When running "ionic serve", it returned the following error:

> ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100 Error: spawn ng EACCES

[image: error message]

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920907/spawn-eacces-error-when-serving-ionic-app help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a permission issue To resolve the issue, run :

```
chmod 755 -R /yourpath/to/node_modules
```

The error may be caused by an installation of a module which was made in `sudo` mode